# Setting up combobox model with QtSql model gives an error

Tags: python, qtsql

I have the following code:

```
    uic.loadUi("mainwindow.ui", self)
    self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
    self.db.setDatabaseName('people.db')

    self.db.open()
    try:
        if self.db.isOpen():
            print('DB open')
    # self.pushButtonClear.clicked.connect(self.clearFields)
    # self.pushButtonSave.clicked.connect(self.insertRowToModel)
        self.pushButtonDelete.clicked.connect(self.deleteTableRow)

        self.model = QSqlRelationalTableModel(db=self.db)
        
        self.model.setTable("person")
        self.model.setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
        
        self.group_index = self.model.fieldIndex("GroupId") #foreign key
        self.model.setRelation(self.group_index, QSqlRelation("Groups", "GroupId", "GroupName"))
        self.model.select()

        self.relModel = self.model.relationModel(self.group_index) 
        self.comboBoxGroup.setModel(self.relModel)
        self.comboBoxGroup.setModelColumn(self.relModel.fieldIndex("GroupName")) 

        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        
        
        self.mapper = QDataWidgetMapper()
        self.mapper.setModel(self.model)

        self.mapper.setItemDelegate(QSqlRelationalDelegate(self))
        
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.lineEditId, 0)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.lineEditForename, 1)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.lineEditSurename, 2)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.dateEditBirthday, 3)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.lineEditCity, 4)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.comboBoxGroup, self.group_index)


        self.mapper.toFirst()
    except:
        self.db.close()
        print('Exception raised')
```

in line: self.comboBoxGroup.setModelColumn(self.relModel.fieldIndex("GroupName"))

it gives an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fieldIndex'
because the self.relModel = self.model.relationModel(self.group_index) results in a None type. It could not be setup. When i enter the column index as a number like this:             self.comboBoxGroup.setModelColumn(self.relModel.fieldIndex(1)) the data shows up at least, but the combobox is not filled. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem:
self.group_index = self.model.fieldIndex("group") #foreign key

field name was incorrect. Now it works but only gives entries where there is
an entry in the group table (inner join)

Comment: i also found out.  self.model.setJoinMode(1) #LeftJoin